# Characteristic polynomials of linear transformations/matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I just have a quick question about characteristic polynomials. It is defined as $$\chi(t) = \det(A - tI)$$ for a matrix $A$. Similarly for a linear transformation using its matrix with respect to some basis. My question is, in the definition of this polynomial, isn't $t \in F$, the field used with the vector space? And hence to prove the Caley-Hamilton theorem we cannot substitute $A$ in the determinant. But what justifies substituting in $A$ *after* obtaining the characteristic polynomial since $t$ is still in the field?

Comment: $t$ isn't anywhere. It's an indeterminate.

Comment: If $\det(A - tI)$ is defined for an indeterminate $t$, then why not for the matrix $A$? The operations will just be different than the standard matrix operations. For example $AI$ will be a big matrix with $A$ along the diagonal etc.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar You're right. The polynomial obtained is formal and if you really wanted to, you can certainly evaluate the determinant in $t$ before obtaining the polynomial. But this requires care. The determinant is no longer the determinant of a matrix with entries in a field, but rather a determinant of a matrix with entries in the matrix ring. Take a look at the wikipedia entry for the [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), specifically at the proof using matrices of endomorphisms. That might address some of your questions.

Comment: @EuYu Thanks for your help. I haven't studied endomorphisms yet so I will come back to the Wikipedia section on it once I learn it. Actually, the first thing I did was to find the answer in Wikipedia but I skipped over the sections that I wasn't familiar with. I am a new user to stackexchange so I am not sure what I am supposed to do now. Do I just leave this post as is?

Comment: Endomorphisms are just linear mappings from a space into itself. Every endomorphism is represented by a square matrix. A matrix of endomorphisms is pretty much just a matrix with matrix entries, but they use endomorphisms to avoid confusion (matrices within matrices get a bit messy). As for the question, I think leaving it would probably be the best. The question is still open since I haven't really provided an answer. I'm sure there are people who can explain in much better detail. One thing you could do is to edit your question to address more specific things you don't understand.